# different json format for list of map

Tags: java, json

for this java code why different result can be produced?

```
List<Map<String,String>> searchSelectBoxJuso = patentService.searchSelectBoxJuso(patentVO);
...
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
​
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
json.put("searchSelectBoxJuso" ,searchSelectBoxJuso);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(json);
```

on Windows

```
{"searchSelectBoxJuso":[{"fieldCodeDetailName":"All","fieldCodeDetailId":"217"},{"fieldCodeDetailName":"City1","fieldCodeDetailId":"21701"},{"fieldCodeDetailName":"City2","fieldCodeDetailId":"21702"}]}
```

​
on Linux

```
{"searchSelectBoxJuso":[{fieldCodeDetailName=All, fieldCodeDetailId=217}, {fieldCodeDetailName=City1, fieldCodeDetailId=21701}, {fieldCodeDetailName=City2, fieldCodeDetailId=21702}]}
```

​
​
​
​
​​

Comment: *FYI* second sample is not JSON

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, "there shouldn't be."  There is *something* wrong in your Linux environment ... or, might it have thrown some exception or put out some message that you didn't catch?

As Justinas just said, "that second response *isn't* valid JSON."  There should be **no** difference between the two outputs.